# How to merge different partitions

Tags: gparted, partitioning, merge

I have Dell 3567 laptop.

I want to merge `sda3` and `sda5` partitions. I don't want to keep data on `sda5`.

I run GParted as bootable but honestly, I’m scared of making mistakes.

Can you help me, please?

[image: my hdd]

Comment: "I am scared of making mistakes." Make a backup regardless of being scared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a backup but  I am not familiar with GParted. What should i do?

Comment: Easiest version: Move the 12.26Gb on sda5 to sda4, delete sda5, alter sda4 and add sda5 to it.

Comment: GParted shows there are some data on `sda5`. Do you want to keep them? @Rinzwind Did you really mean `sda4`, the swap partition?

Comment: @Melebius No, i don't want to keep data on sda5.

Comment: The easiest for me would be to copy the content from sda5 to sda3 and then delete sd5 (from Gparted) and then extend sda3

Comment: Even esier if you don't want to keep tha datas in sda5
Right click on sda5, delete it
And then extend sda3

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. "Right click on sda5, delete it And then extend sda3" It worked for me.

Comment: nope I meant sda3 @Melebius good catch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Backup! Backup!! Backup!! (Make 3 backups)

**Working with partitions is dangerous.** Make sure you have made backups and copies of important data in external media. Avoid making backups in the same disk you are going to work on.

**The following has to be done from a Live USB/DVD.** You should never try to work on partitions from which the system is running. All the partitions has to be unmounted first. In the picture in the question the `/dev/sda4` is mounted as root: `/` as shown by the key symbol next to it. This tells me the Ubuntu is running form this partition. To unmount this partition boot from a Live USB/DVD.

## Step by step instructions

1. Select sda5. You can either click on the top representation or the row in the table below. I have clicked on the 4th row to make it red.

[image]

2. Right click on the selected partition and press delete.

[image]

3. Gparted will show the action you have selected in the bottom panel. Make sure this is what you want to do. There is still time to go back. If you want to go back press the **Undo last operation** orange button. If you are sure what you are doing press the **apply all operations** green check mark button on top.

[image]

4. Once you press the green button. You will see this warning:

[image]

5. This is your last chance to **cancel** the operation. If you still feel sure. Press **Apply**. After you press Apply, Gparted will do it's thing and you will see this:

[image]

6. Note, it must say **All operations successfully completed**. If it does not say that, then something went wrong. **STOP**. If it worked, then close this window and go to the next step.
7. Select sda3 and click on the move resize button:

[image]

8. You will see the resize move window. Drag the right edge all the way to the end:

[image]

9. It should look like this. Press the **Resize/Move** button when you are satisfied.

[image]

10. Now the bottom panel will show the action you want to perform. Make sure this is what you want. If you want to go back press the **Undo last operation** orange button. If you are sure what you are doing press the **apply all operations** green check mark button on top.

[image]

11. Once you press the green button. You will see this warning:

[image]

12. This is your last chance to **cancel** the operation. If you still feel sure. Press **Apply**. After you press Apply, Gparted will do it's thing and you will see this:

[image]

If it must say **All operations successfully completed**, congratulations! You are done. Close the window and close Gparted.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and clear explanation, much appreciated. It will be very helpful to fresh users like me.