# How to delete Kali in dual-boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kali

I have two OSes, Kali and Ubuntu. But I would like to delete Kali and allocate all the disk space to Ubuntu. When I boot, I get the Kali menu. How can I do this, if I do not have access to Ubuntu? 
Also, will the data in Ubuntu be lost?

Comment: If you use the same media/disk for your OSs and if you can, backup your important data to another drive. You can delete with caution the kali linux partition by using Gparted. You can rezise your Ubuntu parition too. However If your problem is just that you can't boot in Ubuntu go to the boot entry menu when you start your PC (probably by holding F10 but it can be different depending the computer model).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not seeing Ubuntu as an option on boot (even when launching the computer boot menu) you may want to boot with a live linux distribution from an usb drive and then repartition your hard drive with `gparted` as recommended by JerareYoshi.

The steps would be:

1. BACK UP ANYTHING YOU DEEM IMPORTANT before doing anything with your partitions.
2. Boot from an USB live distribution. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb) is a tutorial to do so if you don't find one.
3. From the live distribution, open `gparted` and follow the instructions on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005805/how-to-merge-different-partitions) to merge back one partition to the other.
4. Reinstall GRUB or GRUB2 or the boot loader of your preference. [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is yet another tool that repairs your boot sequence. This will allow you to boot your computer into the Ubuntu distribution of now merged hard drive.